# Git, Can't clone repo on windows

Tags: windows, git, ssh, clone

I'm trying to use git on windows to clone a remote repository. I can clone it on my mac fine but on windows I get a problem.

WHen using git bash to clone, I get a message saying the server's host key is not cached in the registry. It asks me to preess y or n to trust the host.

THe problem is that if I press y or n nothing happens. It just hangs there. Should I use OpenSSH instead of PuTTY?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is windows. Use Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that MSysGit starts PLink in the background, i.e. the terminal is not actually connected to the input of PLink. That means that you simply *can't* type anything into PLink.

You simply have to connect to the server once using PLink or PuTTY, answer *Yes* and from then on, you won't be asked again.