# Why does git fetch via hudson fail, while git fetch via the command line works?

Tags: git, hudson, git-fetch

I'm trying to fetch a read-only git repository from github and have it be built via hudson.  This process is failing.

This is the hudson output:

```
Started by an SCM change
Checkout:workspace / d:\hudson\home\jobs\gdcm-hudson\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@19ba1d8
Using strategy: Default
Checkout:workspace / d:\hudson\home\jobs\gdcm-hudson\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@19ba1d8
GitAPI created
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from git://github.com/malaterre/gdcm.git
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" fetch -t git://github.com/malaterre/gdcm.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" ls-tree HEAD
ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
ERROR: Could not fetch from any repository
FATAL: Could not fetch from any repository
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not fetch from any repository
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:674)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:641)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:753)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:735)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:641)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1061)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:479)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:411)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1273)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:129)
```

When I run that fetch command directly via the git bash command line, I get no response (which I assume means it's worked).

I looked at this possible solution:
http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-7141?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

But using that version of the plugin did not change this behavior.

I haven't even gotten to having it work with cmake yet, just downloaded consistently.  How can I get this to work?

edit: This problem is not a repro of [Problem cloning / fetching repository using Git plugin for Hudson on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370371/problem-cloning-fetching-repository-using-git-plugin-for-hudson-on-windows), because I'm not running as a service on a server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I just fixed this exact problem. If you open a windows explorer to `d:\hudson\home\jobs\gdcm-hudson\workspace` you should be able to see a `.git` directory and nothing else. There should be a working copy but there isn't. To fix this you have to "prime" the repository by running

```
git pull git://github.com/malaterre/gdcm.git
```

This should create a bunch of other files in `d:\hudson\home\jobs\gdcm-hudson\workspace` along side the .git directory and you should be able to perform a build in hudson.

Comment: kelloti Do you mean I have to clone my repository to the workspace ?

Comment: It's been a while since I did this, but if it's not cloned you probably need to clone it, so yes. In the answer I gave, I just had to pull once to get it started. It's possible you have an entirely different problem.

Answer (score 5):

This occurred to me on a build that was previously working fine. The solution was just to delete the workspace directory and restart the build.

Answer (score 2):

The Git plugin for Hudson fails only recently on this kind of error message ([issue 6902, July 2010](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-6902?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel)). Before it used to go on silently (which was misleading).

Do you have any submodules defined?
Because it looks like [Git Plugin Bug 4](http://github.com/magnayn/Hudson-GIT-plugin/issues#issue/4)

> I have the following setup:
>
> - a branch called "master", that contains a submodule to another project
> - a branch called "develop", that does not contain a submodule reference
>
> If I configure a Hudson job to build/test the "develop" branch, the build breaks, because it cannot do the submodule checkout. Because this happens before switching to the "develop" branch, the build is broken before anything started.
>
> Solution
>
> I assume the output of **`git ls-tree HEAD`** is scanned for 160000 references to determine which entries are submodules.
>   The ref `HEAD` at that point still points to `master`, I suppose in most cases.
>   Instead of `ls-tree`'ing `HEAD`, maybe do it on the specified branch?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, in my case the problem was that there was a special Git executable configured (in global Hudson settings). This executable failed to run on some of my build hosts due to missing libraries. When using /usr/bin/git instead it worked.

So it looks like the described error message really can indicate *any* Git error at all.