# Hudson, windows2008 and git plugin

Tags: git, windows-server-2008, hudson

I got hudson up and running. Installed git plugin. Created new job, typed in git repository URL, saved and hit 'build now'.

It just freezes. When i cancel build, this is what I get:

> Started by user anonymous
>   Checkout:workspace / C:\Users\taboo_user.TABOO.hudson\jobs\Interreg\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@94aa42
>   Using strategy: Default
>   Checkout:workspace / C:\Users\taboo_user.TABOO.hudson\jobs\Interreg\workspace -   hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@94aa42
>   GitAPI created
>   Cloning the remote Git repository
>   Cloning repository origin
>   $ "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" clone -o origin git@subversion.alise.lv:interreg.git   C:\Users\taboo_user.TABOO.hudson\jobs\Interreg\workspace
>   ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone   git@subversion.alise.lv:interreg.git
>   ERROR: Cause: Error performing C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe clone -o origin   git@subversion.alise.lv:interreg.git C:\Users\taboo_user.TABOO.hudson\jobs\Interreg\workspace
>   null
>   Trying next repository
>   ERROR: Could not clone repository
>   FATAL: Could not clone

I'm googling for about 2 hours now with no results.

Windows event viewer is empty.

Tried setting specific user for hudson windows service, that has correct ssh key, known hosts and is able to git clone from command line repo w/o problems.

Tried to parametrize hudson build with `%HOME%` variable.

Tried to add `c:/program files/git/bin` folder to PATH env variable.

Tried to explicitly tell hudson that it should use `c:/program files/git/bin/git.exe`.

---

There are bunch of info around this error message but nothing helps so far. Got no ideas anymore.

Any help?

---

> echo $USERNAME
>   echo $HOMEPATH
>   echo $HOME

returns

> [workspace] $ sh -xe C:\Users...
>   + echo taboo_user
>   taboo_user
>   + echo '\'
>   \
>   + echo

User name is correct for sure.

Comment: If the Hudson job opens a shell, the you need to echo `$USERNAME` (not `%USERNAME%`), $PATH (not `%PATH%`), ... and so on.

Comment: @VonC looks like it's problem with $HOME variable. Copied `.ssh` dir to `c:/` and it finally works. I wonder why I couldn't set it previously. Kind a tried.

Comment: @Anis L. : strange, you may be able to define HOME rather than leaving that default value '/'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can clone with a specific user outside of Hudson, but cannot within an Hudson Job, that should mean the user and environment used by Hudson is not correct or complete.

In particular, that all "Started by user anonymous" message worries me.

In those case, I always try to simplify the problem, making a simple script-based Hudson job with the only task to display its username, path and environment variable to see exactly *who* will be executing my commands (like git).

Comment: I suspect 'started by user anonymous' is not OS related as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370371/problem-cloning-fetching-repository-using-git-plugin-for-hudson-on-windows/2371573#2371573